# Facebook login - Swift/iOS, how to get users location and hometown?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x

My question is: how to get users location and hometown from facebook account while logging in using Facebook SDK? I can get email, name etc. but when I'm trying to get location and hometown (with permissions set) - I can only get it while logging in using my facebook profile which is connected to my app in Facebook SDK. While logging in with profile other than mine, Facebook API is returning only email and name, but location and hometown are skipped.

I set up User access token in Graph API Explorer, with permissions for user_location and user_hometown (I'm guessing access token is set up only for my account).

Is it possible to set those permissions for all potential users which'll log into my app?

**Code:**

```
func FBLogin() {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile", "user_location", "user_hometown"], from: self) {
        (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("FB Login failed:", err)
            return
        }

        self.showUserInfo()
    }
}

func showUserInfo() {
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, location, hometown, name, first_name, last_name, email, picture.type(large)"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Failed to start graph request")
            return
        }

        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: It means you have not submitted your app for review yet ...

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, that's right I didn't notice that Facebook have that review mechanism when I posted this question.